# UL overflow hidden is not working in both firefox and ie for jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-tabs

I have the following html code and the screenshot is shown below . The overflow hidden for Ul element is not working.kindly let me know.

[image]

```
<div id="sort_columns" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="padding: 2px; position: relative;  margin-left: 0px;">
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
        <a href="#11">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
<a href="#12">aaabbbbbbbbbbbb</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">

</ul>
<div id="11" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` will not clip contents unless it has limited `width` and `height`. Otherwise it will just clear the floating elements inside it so they do not break out of the container. As @Dani commented, this is most likely by design.